# HP Pavillion x2 10.1 detachable

Tags: usb-installation

Okay so recently i have gotten a hp pavillion x2 10-n102na

now i have disabled secured boot, but i still am unable to boot from the USB as i'm trying to install lubuntu onto this systems because windows 10 is not suitable for this due to it only having 2 gb of ram. Any and all help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Lot's of people have had your problem and the answers are outlined [here](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Windows/HP-Pavilion-11-x2-not-booting-from-USB/td-p/4740966)